# How can you rewrite linked external URL for specific files to a locally file using nGinx and a modules like Subs_filter or other output sub mods?

Tags: php, html, apache, nginx, webserver

I am looking for a way to rewrite all links in HTML code matching a specific file type or name from a external domain to locally cached versions automatically.  Is their a way this can possibly be done with something like Apache Mod Rewrite, or preferably nginx?

For example if the local web server has links to http://remotehost.com/unsecure111.jpg I want the local server to substitute all instances of that link with https://localhost.com/cache/secured111.jpg.  Is their any way this can be done in nginx or apache with a mod or extention?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: You need to do that in your code. Rewrite rules in Apache (and the counterpart in Nginx) just handles the server request. They don't rewrite anything in the response (your code).

Comment: You may have some success with `sub_filter` (see [link](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html)) which makes simple substitutions to delivered content.

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_substitute.html

Comment: Richard Smith: Your comment provides a possible solution.  If you can provide a more complete answer I will happily accept it and rep you up.